# Find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac {f(n)} {n(n+1)}}$ where $f(n)$ is the number of $1$s in $n$'s binary expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, binary

We are given the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac {f(n)} {n(n+1)}}$, where $f(n)$ is such a function that it equals the sum of 1's in the binary representation of n.

I'm obliged to find the sum of the series. First, I decided to explicitly prove the convergence of the series. Use for that converging harmonic series,

$\sum {\frac 1 {n^2}}$.
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {f(n)* n^2} {n \cdot (n+1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$

Where $f(n)$ could be represented as $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2 n} m_i$, if we define n as $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2 n} m_i \cdot 2^i$ and $m_i$ is able to take values of 0 or 1.

I can get it intuitively that $f(n)$ doesn't yield $\infty$, when $n \to \infty$. A graph of the function would behave like wave, growing and then returning to 1.
I wrote a script to get some sense of the data, which outputted:

> For p= 10 series=  1.0873015873015872
>   For p= 100 series=  1.3398423025935298
>   For p= 1000 series=  1.3801052489558094
>   For p= 100000 series=  1.3861981879674006

This result looks for me like $ln(4)$, but it doesn't help much, since the solution is supposed to be purely analytical. How can I find a sum?

Comment: As for convergence, we can prove that $f(n)\le \log_2(n+1)$, and the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\ln n}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: For a graph of $f(n)$, see [OEIS A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120/graph)

Comment: $f(n)$ is max$\{r\in\mathbb N:2^r | \binom{2n}n\}$

Comment: @user2425 Would you clarify your comment, pls? Probably I'm failing to understand it. f(10)=2. But I can't get 2 from your formula: binomial(20,10) gives 184756 and... "|" is logical or?

Comment: @wf34 it means that 
$2^r$ divides ${2n\choose n}$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Yep. I see it now. but how on Earth is that possible to come up with such a complicated formula from scratch?

Comment: @wf34 experience, intuition, insight... It's a whole subject on how people came up with new ideas. Mendeleev saw his periodic table of elements as a dream while sleeping=)

Comment: @ajotatxe Would you suggest a way to come up with formula you provided? There is a chance that I will face similar problems soon, so I wanna be prepared. And there are no better way to memorize the formula, then to learn it's derivation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $S$ be the sum (which exists as already noted in the comments).  Use that $f(2n)=f(n)$ and $f(2n+1)=f(n)+1$.  Then splitting the sum in $n$ even and $n$ odd and grouping terms results in the recursion $S= \log(2)+\tfrac{1}{2}S$ so $S = 2\log(2)=\log(4)$.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n(n+1)}\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1+f(n)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{2n(2n+1)}\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}+\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}\right)\\
&=&\log(2) +\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{2n(n+1)}\\
&=&\log(2)+\tfrac{1}{2}S
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac {f(n)} {n \cdot (n+1)}= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac {f(2n)} {(2n) \cdot (2n+1)} + \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {f(2n+1)} {(2n+1) \cdot (2n+2)} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac {f(n)} {(2n) \cdot (2n+1)} +\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {f(n)+1} {(2n+1) \cdot (2n+2)}$ Grouping these terms led me nowhere. Would you give me some extra pointers on how get to your final expression and also why natural logarithm happened to appear in the formula?